# Should I delete my downvoted questions on SO?

Tags: discussion

I used to prune my questions, removing the ones that had come to rest at 0 or below (though they may have had some plus votes, I know). Is this a good idea, bad idea, and why?

I think it keeps SO more tidy (though I do like all of my own questions, myself)...

**Edit**: I tried to delete some questions and it was impossible because they had upvoted answers. Which is the case with all of my questions. (I think that questions should just get rated as a sum of some proportion of their answers. Can someone point me to a discussion of that here on meta?)...

Comment: Heh... I thought about mentioning the upvoted answer restriction when replying, but decided to generalize it instead (don't delete questions with good answers even if they haven't been upvoted). Ah, well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Occasionally I will post a question (or answer) that has a negative 1 downvote, and a lively discussion has taken place in the comments.  If you delete the question (or answer), that entire thread is lost.

I deleted one of my answers like that recently because, although the comments discussion was interesting, it wasn't really adding to the question anymore, and my desire to reduce clutter overcame my interest in the comments.  But, for a moment, it was a difficult decision.

I guess I get to play benevolent dictator on my own questions and answers in this regard.

Comment: I wish I could, but I always get upvoted answers on my questions => no deletion. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should think about why people downvotes it in the first place first...

And then edit accordingly, correcting misunderstandings and whatnot

But if after some efforts the community wouldn't like it... then it deserves to be deleted

I hate to see good questions gets deleted/closed just because the author made some silly mistakes...

Comment: I don't make mistakes. My questions are annoying. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091764/what-would-be-a-good-criterion-for-code-golf

Answer (score 4):

I delete anything down voted because A) Don't want 'more' people to down vote it, and B) if its a bad answer, it shouldn't be on there.

I normally have my answers open in another tab for 10 minutes after I answer them to see how its received anyway, so I normally catch the down voted stuff immediately.

In response to Shog's comment, I believe this practice works for questions too.

Comment: Note that he's asking about questions, not answers...

Comment: Nope, I don't think that's a wise idea, sometimes specially on SO people are more keen to downvote , they are in a hurry and then you get downvoted even when you don't deserve it, like on this answer of mine :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633405/using-goto-keyword-in-c/17633458#17633458 ...... Another guy had one wrong point in his answer, but I had none , I said exactly what was needed , at least didn't write anything wrong for that matter.

Comment: And the downvote was lightning fast , I didn't even get any chance for thinking let alone going for edit, later I edited my answer which wasn't wrong at all but I tried to make it better and left a comment * " I haven't said it prints 0 then why downvote on my answer, please explain" * . The big-hearted people noticed and removed the downvotes and I was even upvoted after that but it has still a score of (-1) . Now, should I delete my answer , nope , because some wise people even upvoted . Why should I care about grumpy people trying to flood their grudges down here.... contd...

Comment: I should not delete answer for all that was just a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel that the answer is good and you don't deserve the downvotes, then delete it.

If you feel that the downvotes are probably justified, get rid of it. We even have a badge (Peer Pressure) to encourage users to get rid of answers and questions that do not get agreed on by the community.

Comment: Wait... did you miss a word in that first sentence?

Comment: You put delete it in both cases :x

Comment: The question was about deleting one's own question, not answer.

Answer (score 2):

If a good answer has been posted to your question, then leave it - someone may still find it useful. Take the opportunity to improve your question, if possible.

Otherwise, delete it - that way, someone asking a similar question in the future won't run the risk of being marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Ironically, there are always good answers on my downvoted questions, and all of them have upvotes AND NOT JUST FROM ME. But I think you're right, my rep be damned...

Answer (score 2):

From a selfish rep score point of view then yes delete them. Why? When a recalculation is done you'll regain the lost rep.

Comment: Not really.  The downvotes no longer appear in your history, but your score stays the same.

Comment: Are you saying that the system periodically sweeps everyone's entire history of questions and answers, and recalculates all the scores?  I haven't seen that.

Comment: It's a manual process that can be done for everyone or just individuals. There are other questions/answers on this here on meta. Search for "recalc" or "recalculation".

Comment: It's not done very often as you usually lose rep due to upvoted questions/answers being deleted.