# Delete downvoted post before closure with answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes, closed-questions

I've just asked a question on Stack Overflow and I found out, it was a stupid question which I shouldn't put up there at first so I decided to delete the post.

However, the post had an answer and I couldn't delete it.

But, I faced a downvote of -7 when it closed.

And even after the closure I got 3 more down votes, adding up to a total of -10 on that question.

Why can users downvote a closed post? And is there a way I can remove that stupid post?

Comment: I would flag for moderator attention and ask them to delete it.

Comment: see: [How can someone downvote my post to a closed question? What does closing really mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99035/165773)

Comment: Hm, I was under the impression you couldn't delete your question if it had _upvoted_ answers, the answer in yours isn't upvoted. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @Robuust this comment is a side note, [Should I delete my downvoted questions on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9567/166025) has some good points, specially [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9621/166025).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed questions are not necessarily dead questions. You still have the chance to correct or improve your post so it can be reopened. Therefore voting will remain to function as it normally would.

And you can always flag your post for moderator attention, explaining you want to have it deleted and why you want that.

Comment: Even if we replace [closed] with [this isn't dead, it can be re-opened if improved], people will still think their question is dead <sigh>

Comment: @YannisRizos Yep. I've often thought about how we could convey this idea of closure being temporary somewhat better, but I'm still drawing a blank on that one.

Comment: People won't even care to look at closed posts, as @YannisRizos mentions

Comment: @Robuust I look at closed questions all the time (but not everyone does), but my comment wasn't really about that, what I meant is that people feel their _own_ question is dead, just because it was closed. I'm talking specifically about the askers, not everyone else.

Comment: @Robuust I would rather argue that not many questions get reopened because the OP does not put in the necessary effort (for whatever reason). There are many questions which are justifiably closed where I feel they might stand a chance of reopening with some effort of the OP. And as Yannis, I do myself often look at and edit closed questions. But it's true that not everybody does so.

Comment: Creating a new question with better contents is faster than waiting for it to be reopened, as it needs 4 more votes except your own?

Comment: @Robuust You could try that. If it's too similar though, you might run the risk of it being closed as an exact duplicate.